# Filtering data from AWS Amplify Graphql API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, aws-amplify, amazon-dynamodb

Graphql Schema :

```
type Media @model
{
  id: ID!
  title: String
  type: String
}
```

Sample Data :

```
{
      id: "some ID",
      title: "sample media1",
      type: "image/png",
}

{
      id: "some ID",
      title: "sample media2",
      type: "video/mp4",
}
```

I'd like to fetch only data that its type contains string "image".

> type: "image/mp4"

I know that I can get some data based on title in this way.

```
import { API, graphqlOperation } from "aws-amplify"
import * as queries from "@src/graphql/queries"
...
let title = "sample media1"
const medias = await API.graphql(
                 graphqlOperation(queries.listMedias, { filter: { title: { eq: title } } })
               )
```

Is there any similar way to get data that one of its attributes contains a specific value?

**"contains" not "exact same"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in AWS Amplify [documentation](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/graphqlapi/query-data/q/platform/js#filtering-queries) you can use corresponding [DynamoDB queries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Condition.html). One of this queries is contains, but it is dependent on the type of field that your are doing filtering. List of all operators supported by DynamoDB:

- EQ
- NE
- LE
- LT
- GE
- GT
- NOT_NULL
- NULL
- CONTAINS
- NOT_CONTAINS
- BEGINS_WITH
- IN
- BETWEEN

So in your example:

```
import { API, graphqlOperation } from "aws-amplify"
import * as queries from "@src/graphql/queries"
...
let title = "sample media1"
const medias = await API.graphql(
                 graphqlOperation(queries.listMedias, { filter: { title: { contains: title } } })
               )
```

Comment: Thanks Ivan, your suggestion works well for me.